# Docker compose host variable in extra_hosts not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with `.env` file, for example the `.env` file has this `HOSTNAME=a1.test.com`, and a `docker-compose` file has this:

```
...
extra_hosts:
  - "${HOSTNAME}:1.1.1.1"
  - "test.com:1.1.1.1"
```

When I run the container the `/etc/hosts` file content is:

```
1.1.1.1          
1.1.1.1    test.com
```

So the docker compose not putting the variable data during the run process.

I tried this `hostname: "${HOSTNAME}"` and it is working fine the host name of the container is correct `a1.test.com`.

Any idea how can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4):

I've tried your case, and it works fine on my side:

```
version: '2'
services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    command: sleep 9999
    extra_hosts:
      - "${HOSTNAME}:1.1.1.1"
      - "test.com:1.1.1.1"
```

and here is what I get in the container

```
cat /etc/hosts
...
1.1.1.1 a1.test.com
1.1.1.1 test.com
```

*(edit: indentation)*

Comment: It was my mistake, I had typo in .env file

Comment: I'm getting this eror: 
ERROR: for cron  Cannot create container for service cron: bad format for add-host: ":1.1.1.1"

with: "${HOSTNAME}:1.1.1.1"